# Changed nameservers lost email

Tags: email, exchange, domain, mx-record

My client had a website on Wix and his domain name was registered at Aruba.it. I set up a new website for him with my host (1&1 Internet) and I have today changed the nameservers with his registrar (Aruba) to point to my host. All went fine and I can see his new website. However his email has broken in the process and he cannot receive any new email. I discovered in my 1&1 Account that the email now appears to be setup there (I assume this is what happens when I change the nameservers) as i have created a new mailbox and can see his mail arriving in webmail for 1&1 internet.

His setup at home is quite complicated and he uses Exchange, which he thinks is setup to work with Aruba - I have no experience of Exchange - I was hoping the easy way around this would be to update the incoming and outgoin mail server in his email client but I don't know how to do this with Exchange (which is also connected to Office365 somehow).

I thought the next best thing to do was to send the mail server back to Aruba from my 1&1 Internet account, but then I am not sure what I need to do, I assume it's related to the MX Record and possibly A record, but I do not know what i need to enter into them - I have emailed Aruba to see if they can tell me what to enter, but I am concerned of the delay in a response.

Comment: Ummm... Why are you selling services you don't understand?

Answer (score 0):

Well, you should add to your DNS same e-mail related entries(MX, DKIM, SPF and e.g) as it was on old DNS servers and it will solve your problem.

Comment: Thanks, I can't seem to find any detail on what the old dns used to be in Aruba - presumably because I have changed nameservers? Since changing nameservers in Aruba the only thing I can see in relation to DNS settings is an option to reset the nameservers back to Aruba

Comment: @DanielTink you could try to dig http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2012/02/dig-command-examples on Aruba's DNS.

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion would be to change the nameservers back to Aruba, then change just the www and regular domain "A" addresses *at Aruba's nameservers* to point to the IP address of your new 1&1 website for him.

By changing the nameservers themselves, you have changed *all* of his DNS settings, not just where his website points.

However, you may have already lost all the settings that Aruba had for his domain by changing the nameservers.  You can try setting them back to Aruba's default (which may or may not reset his MX records to whatever they were before), then just updating the "A" records for www. and his bare domain name to the IP address 1&1 is using for his domain.

Comment: Thanks Eric - I have just found some old settings that were applied to his Aruba account to do with an MX record -

########-com.mail.protection.outlook.com

I assume this has something to do with his Exchange setup - Do you think i could set the mx record in 1&1 Internet to this and it'll be sorted? Or should i try your reset suggestion

Comment: Copying the MX record (setting it the host you mention) should get his mail delivering again.  However, there may be other settings besides the MX for spf or other spam prevention settings (typically in TXT records).  You should copy those as well.